# My 2dGameEngine is very laggy

Tags: java, game-engine, lag

I originally wrote started writing this on windows, and it ran pretty smoothly, though it occasionaly would freeze up; but, after i switched to linux, the graphics are very very choppy. I expect it worked before because I had the right drivers to my video card, but after the switch, I may be getting less performance from it do to bad drivers. Although, a 2d game engine should be able to run on pretty bad computers. I was wondring why it is running so slow, and how i could make run faster. There are other classes aside from the one below, but the one below contains most of main functions of the program.

```
package Platformer;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent.Type;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public abstract class GameComponent extends JPanel{
    //delete this i think
    public static int ticks=0;
    public Rectangle box;

    private final int FPS=40;
    public int xMovement=0;
    public int yMovement=0;
    public final int A=0,D=1,S=2,W=3,SPACE=4;
    public boolean[] keyPressed=new boolean[5];
    private InputController keyListener;
    public ArrayList<Entity> Entities=new ArrayList<Entity>();
    HashMap sounds=new HashMap();

    public boolean drawLines=false;
    public int xAxisLines=40;
    public int yAxisLines=27;

    Quadtree quad=new Quadtree(0,new Rectangle(0,0,1920,1080));


    public GameComponent(){
        keyListener=new InputController();
        box=new Rectangle(90,90,20,20);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow(true);
        run();

    }
    public void run(){
        addKeyListener(keyListener);

        Timer timer=new Timer(1000/FPS, new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //movement();

                gameLoop();
                collisions();
                repaint();
                ticks++;
                if(ticks==360 || ticks==1000){
                    try{
                        playSound("spun");



                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        });
        timer.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g.create();
        //g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        //g2d.fill(box);




        for(Entity entity: Entities){
            g2d.drawImage(entity.IMAGE, entity.getX(),entity.getY(), entity.IMAGE.getWidth(), entity.IMAGE.getHeight(), null);
            g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(entity.NAME), entity.getX(), entity.getY());
        }
        ///draw lines in window if enabiled
        if(drawLines){
            drawLines(g2d);
        }
        ///do collisions

        g2d.dispose();

    }

    class InputController implements KeyListener{

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                keyPressed[W]=true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                keyPressed[S]=true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                keyPressed[A]=true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                keyPressed[D]=true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                keyPressed[SPACE]=true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                keyPressed[W]=false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                keyPressed[S]=false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                keyPressed[A]=false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                keyPressed[D]=false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                keyPressed[SPACE]=false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

    public abstract void gameLoop();
    public void drawLines(Graphics2D g2d){
        for(int i=0;i<1920;i+=1920/xAxisLines){
            g2d.drawLine(i, 0, i, 1080);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<1080;i+=1080/yAxisLines){
            g2d.drawLine(0, i, 1920, i);
        }
    }
    public void collisions(){
    ////collisions!

        ArrayList<Entity> returnEntities=new ArrayList<Entity>();
        quad.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<Entities.size();i++){
            quad.insert(Entities.get(i));
        }

        for(int i=0;i <Entities.size();i++){
            returnEntities.clear();
            returnEntities=quad.retrieve(returnEntities,Entities.get(i));

            for(Entity e:returnEntities){
                //System.out.println(Entities.get(i).NAME+" could collide with "+e.NAME);
                if(Math.abs(Entities.get(i).getX()-e.getX())<= Entities.get(i).IMAGE.getWidth()/2+e.IMAGE.getWidth()/2 && Math.abs(Entities.get(i).getY()-e.getY())<= Entities.get(i).IMAGE.getHeight()/2+e.IMAGE.getHeight()/2 && Entities.get(i)!=e){
                    //System.out.println(Entities.get(i).NAME+" is colliding with "+e.NAME);
                }
            }
        }
            ////collisions!
        /*
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(quad.getIndex(Entities.get(0))));
        System.out.println(Entities.get(0).bounds.x);
        System.out.println(Entities.get(0).bounds.y);
        */
    }
    public void playSound(String fileName) throws IOException, 
      UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {
        File clipFile=new File("assets//"+fileName+".wav");

        class AudioListener implements LineListener {
            private boolean done = false;
            @Override public synchronized void update(LineEvent event) {
              Type eventType = event.getType();
              if (eventType == Type.STOP || eventType == Type.CLOSE) {
                done = true;
                notifyAll();
              }
            }
            public synchronized void waitUntilDone() throws InterruptedException {
              while (!done) {}
            }
        }
        class SoundThread implements Runnable  {
            AudioListener listener = new AudioListener();
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
            public SoundThread() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException{
              audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(clipFile);
            }

          @Override
          public void run() {
              try{
                  Clip clip=AudioSystem.getClip();
                  clip.addLineListener(listener);
                  clip.open(audioInputStream);
                  try{
                      clip.start();
                      listener.waitUntilDone();
                  }
                  finally{
                      clip.close();
                  }
              }
              catch(Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              finally{
                  try {
                      audioInputStream.close();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
          }

        }
        Thread thread=new Thread(new SoundThread());
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

Well you have written it very Procedurally, rather than object orientated. you have lots of lists being iterated, Maybe if you refactor it then you may be able to speed it up, Is there anywhere that we can get the code (github etc) as with just this snippet there is not much we can do to help.

Comment: Can you explain how it is written very procedurally, rather than object oriented?

Comment: The classic example is space invaders, if you have a main loop that does the movement and firing etc, that is procedural, in an OO world you would do stuff like the laser base listens for its move commands and fire command, when it fires it creates a new "bullet" object that has a start position and vector/direction to move. Then when the bullet detects it has hit something it notified the hit object that it has done so and lets the object decide whether it should blow up, do nothing , or tell the bullet to reverse its direction. etc.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me some examples of where I do this though?

Comment: I will look into the code when i can (RL is a pain sometimes) and get back to you when i have something useable

Comment: Object oriented is not designed to reduce your time - it is designed to organize your software. It is overbloating.

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, OO will typically slow you down and a lot of it should be avoided in the high-perf areas of your code, which you have identified carefully using a profiler. Outside these areas OO is a really good idea.

Comment: Ok I have still not had time to do much in streamlining the code, however i have refactored it slightly and on my Windows PC its running a little smoother as well as exiting when closing the window, one hint maybe check the screen size before setting the window size as it was too big for my laptop screen, https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gim9p0i3lrl1ni/2dGameEngine.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

Any specific reason for doing `Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g.create()` and `g2d.dispose();`?

Can't you just `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;`? It will probably improve performance.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR; but managed to find 2 fundamental mistakes:

- In Swing **never** override `paint()` to do graphics.

Use the override-safe `paintComponent()`. (In additional to @YoavAharoni's point, don't create new graphic contexts every time it repaints.)

- Never make long lasting tasks inside the EDT.

In your case, you call `gameLoop()`, `collisions()`, and `playSound()` - which I assume as time consuming - inside the timer's event method. Instead, use `java.util.Timer` or threads.

If you must use the EDT, as to render long lasting graphics, use a `SwingWorker`. (Note: `repaint()` *may* be called outside EDT)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what IDE are you using, but I recommend you to do a profiling. Eclipse has a nice plugin for that.

- Yourkit: free trial only, but pretty good https://www.yourkit.com/features/eclipse/
- Eclipse java profiler, you can find it on the marketplace
- Netbeans https://profiler.netbeans.org/

Once I had to wrote a game myself, and my problem was with the size of the images:

```
``g2d.drawImage(entity.IMAGE, entity.getX(),entity.getY(), entity.IMAGE.getWidth(), entity.IMAGE.getHeight(), null);``
```

I had to decrease the size under 40kb for each image to run normally.

Another thing is that you switch of some elments on your UI, and see what makes a big performance boost, then you can tweak that component.